# URL Keep Adding Backslash Django

Tags: django

I need your help in fixing this issue.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
path('menu', views.menu, name='menu'),
path('close', views.close, name='close'),
path('lead', views.lead, name='lead'),
path('audience', views.audience, name="audience"),
path('audience/<action>', views.audience, name="audience")
```

]

That's my code URLs but I keep getting a backslash at the end of the URL.

For instance, if I link to dashboard/menu, I get dashboard/menu/

Answer (score 6):

Slash is automatically appended when [settings.APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#append-slash) is set to `True` (which it is, by default).

to change the behaviour, change the value to `False` in your `settings.py`:

```
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

Comment: Okay, how do i remove it? Because this is only happening in one app, I have two app Account.urls and Dashboard.urls

Account.urls works fine but Dashboard proves otherwise.

Plus I checked my settings.py file but can't find any append in it

Comment: you dont remove it, set the value to False instead (see above)

Comment: I don't have APPEND_SLASH  in my settings.py file. Should I add it?

Comment: yes that's how `settings.py` works. If you dont like the default value and you want to change it, you add it with the desired value.

Comment: @JoeMayami any more questions? If not, can you mark the question as solved?